# I get a error when I try install auto-complete in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, lisp

I'm newbie in emacs...I've a few days and I think emacs is awesome but I get a error when I try install auto-complete...I install it from http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/   the installation works (I use the makefile)...but when I put this lines inside my emacs.d

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

I get this error

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/yo/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-dictionary-directories

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace
```

I've my folder .emacs in /home/yo/.emacs and inside this I've the folder ac-dic..inside this there are c++ mode..lisp mode ruby mode...etc..etc...etc.....

my autocomplete.el is inside my .emacs too...what am I doing wrong??...thanks!!!

Answer (score 27):

`ac-dictionary-directories` is defined in the auto-complete.el, so obviously emacs will not find it. So simply change the order of the statements:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
```

Now, it should work.

Comment: just want to add that this didn't work for me... Emacs 24.2.2, auto-complete v1.3.1. and no config for yasnippet at all.

Comment: +1. Also I need to add (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d") above those three lines.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is that `add-to-list` wants to prepend to an existing list, but there is no such variable at the time you're calling it.

You could use `(setq 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")` instead or follow the advice in the help for add-to-list:

> If you want to use `add-to-list' on a variable that is not defined
>   until a certain package is loaded, you should put the call to`add-to-list'
>   into a hook function that will be run only after loading the package.
>   `eval-after-load' provides one way to do this.  In some cases
>   other hooks, such as major mode hooks, can do the job.

In other words something like:

```
(eval-after-load 'auto-complete-config
  '(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict"))
```

Or, finally, you could just set the variable after the `require`, but I'm not sure how that interacts with auto-complete's initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

`.emacs.` is normally an elisp file and `.emacs.d` is the directory.  Looks like you are treating them the other way round.  You put the

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

in `~/.emacs`, not `.emacs.d`.

Or, your question is not clear.  What does your `~/.emacs` look like?

EDIT:

Or, you want to do

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

instead of

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

> I've my folder .emacs in /home/yo/.emacs and inside this I've the folder ac-dic..inside this there are c++ mode..lisp mode ruby mode...etc..etc...etc.....

`~/.emacs` should be a file.  Not a directory.

> but when I put this lines inside my emacs.d

`~/.emacs.d/` should be a directory

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was due to the fact that I copied the auto-complete files from an other computer. To solve it, I redownload the [sources](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/index.html#Latest_Stable) then I recompile it and copied in my .emacs.d

 `cd auto-complete
 make byte-compile
 cp *.el *.elc ~/.emacs.d`